# Wordpress, Editing home page exerpt

Tags: wordpress

If this is off topic or not fit for stackoverflow, I apologize. I searched for an answer elsewhere but couldn't find it easily. Also I figured it'd be nice to add to the stackoverflow knowledge base.

I'm trying to edit the title and excerpt/description that appears in my site. 
[image]

In my case, it says

```
(no title)
```

and

```
This is the home page's excerpt.
```

---

**Edit:** 
This the html content of my home page:

```
Journey to the Thingamajig is a web game by Ethan Fischer. It features 7
dazzling levels, running, jumping, punching, and the ability to feel like a
badass.


[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/277446442" params="auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true" width="100%" height="70" iframe="true" /]

 
<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 75%;">
<p style="font-size: 100%; color: white;">"Breathtaking."</p>
<p style="font-size: 40%; color: grey;">-Ethan Fischer</p>
<p style="font-size: 100%; color: white;">"I can't stop playing"</p>
<p style="font-size: 40%; color: grey;">-Ethan Fischer</p>
<p style="font-size: 100%; color: white;">"A remarkable achievement"</p>
<p style="font-size: 40%; color: grey;">-Ethan Fischer</p>
<p style="font-size: 100%; color: white;">"Redefines what it means to be a videogame in the 21st century. This is one of the most important works of art ever released."</p>
<p style="font-size: 40%; color: grey;">-Ethan Fischer</p>

</div>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 400%;"><strong><u><b><a style="color:
#e5b909;" href="http://gamejolt.com/games/journey-to-the
thingamajig/194130">PLAY IT</a></b></u></strong></p>
```

---

**Edit 2:** 
I also changed the 'slug' and 'excerpt' under the More Options tab on the left. This still didn't update the preview seen on facebook (see 2nd screenshot)

[image]

---

**How/where do I change social media preview, i.e. the title and excerpt shown in facebook when I share the homepage?**

Comment: hi it is blog post or any page content (home page or about us page something)

Comment: Okay I tried adding a plain text description at the beginning of my home page. (I edited question to show my code). Still has not updated excerpt or title in the preview on facebook. Maybe it takes a bit of time to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Settings - General and changing the Site Title and Tagline.

Comment: Okay I tried this but nothing has changed in the facebook preview. Maybe it takes some time to update though?

Comment: You can plug your website address in [Facebook's Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and then click Scrape Again to tell FB to update the info! :)

Comment: Yes! The combination of these two things made it happen for me. Thank you @shipshape!